# Grub installed in linux efi partition can't load Ubuntu generic linux

Tags: system, grub-efi, ubuntu-minimal

I have Arch linux and windows on a dual boot efi. Currently windows uefi partition is on dev/sda2, arch efi is in dev/sda5 with grub bootloader installed on it. Arch root is on dev/sdb1 with swap on dev/sdc1 and home on dev/sdc2. Works fine.

Installed Ubuntu bionic  minimal with linux generic kernel and the base system only. No desktop and bootloader. Installed on dev/sdb3 with dev/sdc4 as swap for ubuntu. No separate home partition for Ubuntu.
After installation ran os prober with mounted Ubuntu root on /mnt and windows efi partition on mnt2. os prober found ubuntu, windows and arch. Generated grub cfg. Grub loads Arch and windows fine.

For Ubuntu it says the partition with uuid of dev/sdb3 where it's installed as not found. I checked grub cfg, fstab of Ubuntu. The root partition uuid is correct. Why it gives no such partition is where I'm stuck.

I noticed grub cfg has msdos as label type. After manually changing to part_gpt snd msdos4 to gpt5 it says cannot find vmlinuz in path where it exists:/dev/sdb3.
Lost now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could make your question more readable by proof-reading it for spelling errors, by breaking it up into smaller paragraphs and by using appropriate markdown formatting.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Sorry,did not know on enter rather than a line break it gets posted :) . I cant see the option Try Ubuntu on the minimal installation USB. I get Command line install as the second option and it proceeds more or less like expert install.Tried other options but cant get it anywhere.Is there something im missing ? Or can i use something from Arch to get the information for debugging. Thanks Oldfred for your help.

Comment: I had customized the installer to copy the efi image to the root of the usb to start installer in efi mode.Then=> https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI=> Force grub-efi installation to the removable media path .In the installer if one selects not to force grub installation it creates generates the grub.cfg,copies 3 efi files only.the grub.cfg only points to the actual boot directory with full grub installation of Ubuntu along with grub.cfg.Now running prober from Arch generates the grub cfg in its efi directory,which boots.Its the same grub cfg without bootloader.A firmware problem?DNo answers really